# Display "Day entities" that contain Stuff, by day and by period

Tags: gui-design, windows-os

I have something like `Things that happened this day` that can be either of TypeA or TypeB.

I want to display `Day` items per period and also display inside each `Day` item some info about its TypeA's and TypeB's items.

Example

```
-- This Month
---- Day1
------TypeA-Example.Description()
------TypeA-Example2.Description()
------TypeB-Example.Description()
---- Day2
-- Last 4 Months
```

At the moment I use the `DevExpress` `GalleryControl`. This allows items to be added that contain only title and description among an image.

[image]

**Question:** How can I efficiently show this set of entities?

Comment: Is your application on a portable or stationary platform? (Considering screen size)

Comment: We've set minimum resolution at 1366*768 and the dimensions of this area is around 1120 * 370. In this area I want to be able to show at least 3 days horizontally this makes the area of each day around 400*220.
The target platform is casual computers running windows xp and latter with max resolution of HD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best analog for this that I can think of is calendars which list activities on a particular day. The day may have many events or few, so the height of a particular item should be flexible. Thus I would use a control that allows for days with mixed heights.

I don't believe that the ordering in this list will be confusing, as the variable height of items will encourage vertical scanning rather than horizontal.

Indicate that the items can be individually selected by making them links. It is a bit odd for an application to use web style links, but it's one of the most compact way to afford clicking. I indicated the difference between A and B with color, but you could use typography, background, or nothing if the difference is not important to display.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzYpr5.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: THANKS for the detailed answer.  As seen in my example, I already use different colors for TypeA and TypeB (Green/Orange) and also a state icon (red and green in the right bottom corner).

If I use your proposed design, I'll have to somehow stack Days. Do you have any known (non WPF) controls that support this?

We use devexpress along with default winform controls.

Comment: I apologize, my UX experience is almost solely web based, so I am not a good person to ask about what controls provide specific functionality. I can say that Outlook Contacts uses a similar control; perhaps you could ask on [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) what control works most like the Outlook Contact view?